# How does email routing work when deleting a Google Apps domain?

Tags: google-workspace

Our business is changing domain names and needs to migrate from one Google Apps for Business account to another. I've taken care of the data migration, but now we need to redirect mail from the old domain to the new domain while deleting the old account so I can add it as a secondary domain in the new account.

I can't seem to add the old domain as a secondary while the old domain's apps account still exists.

What's the best way to do this?

Will domain level email routing from the old domain continue to wait during the 5 day waiting period that Google warns of while deleting the apps account?

We don't want to have any downtime during the transition.